# this.state.cartIsh.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The browser is saying my 'this.state.cartIsh.map' is not a function. Here's my code below. (BTW i'm using an online code editor. [Codesandbox](http://codesandbox.io) )

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      cartIsh: [],
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.cartIsh.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div style={cartItemStyle}>
              <div style={selectedStyle}> </div>
              <div style={idStyle}> {item.ID} </div>
              <div> {item.Quantity}, {item.Name} </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What does `console.log( typeof this.state.cartIsh)` before the `return` say?

Comment: wat browser do you use ?

Comment: I have tried your code in Codesandbox and it worked just fine with both empty array `cartIsh` and not empty.

Comment: I dont know what went wrong. I was using Google Chrome. Ive switched up to stackblitz now and the code is working fine. Thanks.